# Java Cryptography Affine cipher wrong output

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, output

I am trying to do a affine methods but my output is totally wrong and I  have no clue how to fix it, can anyone look at it and tell me what is wrong

```
public void Affine(int a, int b){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    int len = jMesaj.getText().length(); //length of the input
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        char currentChar = jMesaj.getText().charAt(i);
        char finalChar = ((char)(currentChar +(a*i + b)% 26));
        builder.append(finalChar);
    }
    String result = builder.toString();
    builder.delete( 0 , builder.length() -1 );

    jEncryptionResult.setText(result); //display result in jTextArea 
}
```

Comment: Please clarify "my output is totally wrong"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you are assuming that 'A' = 1, 'B' = 2, etc. Also, the [affine algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_cipher) is slightly different. if you're using 26 as module it makes me thing that you are cyphering from 'A' to 'Z'. If that's true then try adding an offset in this line, something like this:

```
char finalChar = (char)((a*(currentChar - 'A') + b) % 26 + 'A');
```

Answer (score 0):

The char is a value between 0-65536 (2 bytes, 2^16). It's a little bit messy with the Unicode stuff, at least if you want to use esötéric çhåräcters in your seçret cömmünìcåtiön.

If you know your alphabet on beforehand a simpler implementation would be to use

```
String str = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; 
char[] alphabet = str.toCharArray(); //make sure it's sorted for binarySearch to work!
```

and then lookup the positions of your incoming chars through `java.utils.Array.binarySearch(alphabet, char)`, make your maths on the returned `int` array position (modulo the length of the `alphabet` array) and look up the encrypted letter from this position put it in your out-message `StringBuilder`.

You could also create two `HashMaps<char,char>`, one for encryption and the other for decryption.

Comment: It's a little bit more complicateted that way

Comment: As always; it depends.

Answer (score 0):

/**
*    Class    : AffineCipher
* 
*    @author  : Oracle
*
*    Written  : Aug 26, 2013 9:01:28 PM 
*
*    Compiler : NetBeans 7.3.1
*
*    Platform : Windows 7 Ultimate 
*/

package enigma;

public class AffineCipher {

```
public String Encryption(String plainText, int a , int b){

     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
     int len = plainText.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){

       char currentChar = plainText.toUpperCase().charAt(i);

       int IntcurrentChar = (int) currentChar - 65;

       int finalCharInt = (a* IntcurrentChar + b) % 26;

       int FinalCharint = finalCharInt + 65;

       char finalChar = (char) FinalCharint;

       builder.append(finalChar); 
    }
        String result = builder.toString().toLowerCase();



    return result;

}//end String Encryption

public String Encrypt(String plainText, int a, int b ){

    int len = plainText.length();
             StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

             String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

             for(int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++){

             int charPos = alphabet.indexOf(plainText.charAt(i));
             /*
              *Read the character from input and get the position of the it in string
              */
             int keyVal = (a* charPos+b) % 26; 

             /*
              * keyVal store the position of the character that replace the one from the input
              */
             char finalChar = alphabet.charAt(keyVal);

             sb.append(finalChar);

            }
             String result = sb.toString();

return result;   

}
```